# Adding background images in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

Hi I am very new to Ionic 2.Can someone help with telling how to add a background image in a project in Ionic 2(specifically the below one)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in the scss file of the ionic page. Inside the url you can give the relative path where the image resides.

```
body {
    background-image: url(".. /assets/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: how to create the grey/white part?can we customise backgrounds?